# Best way to handle array in object in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm learning how to use handlebars, and I'm not sure what's the best way to display my object.

Basically, I have a complex object to display. The object is something like this:

```
{
  bookList: [{
    name: "the name",
    reviewers: ["a reviewer name", "another reviewer"]
  }]
}
```

Then my handlebars template needs to display something like:

```
{{#each bookList}}
<tr class="row">
<td class="cell">{{name}}</td>
<td class="cell">need to display comma separated names here, like this: "a reviewer name, another reviewer</td>
<td class="cell">display number of reviewers here, like this: "2"</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

But I'm not sure how I can do that, or what the best way to do it is. I could easily pre-format my javascript object in javascript before I pass it to the handlebars template, and just add fields like "commaSeparatedReviewers", and "numberOfReviewers", but it seems like it would be more efficient / better to do it with handlebar helpers I think?

Can I use handlebar helpers to do something like create a comma separated string out of an array, and count the elements in an array? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{reviewers.length}}` within that loop will give you the number of reviewers (size of the array).

AFAIK there is no helper for easily joining an array with a delimiter (eg. getting a comma separated list of your reviewers), but you can write a custom helper such as here:

[GitHub feature request](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/133)

Here's a solution someone posted for implementing a `join` helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('join', function(val, delimiter, start, end) {
    var arry = [].concat(val);
    delimiter = ( typeof delimiter == "string" ? delimiter : ',' );
    start = start || 0;
    end = ( end === undefined ? arry.length : end );
    return arry.slice(start, end).join(delimiter); 
});
```

Comment: Yep, I ended up figuring out how to write one pretty similar to your suggested solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For anyone googling, you could also just implement it literally:

```
{{#each array}}
    {{this}}{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Spot on, the perfect answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Older question but it turned up while I was searching for a solution to a similar issue. I figured I'd share my solution.

Handlebars now supports a few properties that may not have been available two years ago. namely `@first` and `@last`. See [Handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html)

You should be able to do something like this:

```
{{#each bookList}}
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell">{{name}}</td>
    <td class="cell">
      {{#each reviewers}}
        {{#unless @first}}, {{/unless}}
        {{this.code}}
      {{/each}}</td>
    <td class="cell">{{reviewers.length}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```